# Mesos failed with Error: Failed to load class ... Command exited with status 101 Spark3, Mesos 1.9.0, Jdk headless 11 RHEL 7

Tags: apache-spark, java-11, mesos, rhel7

We current project works with jdk8, Cent7, Spark 2.3.1 and MESOS 1.4.1.  We are upgrading to jdk11 headless and RHEL7, Spark 3.0.0 and Mesos 1.9.0.

On a new cluster that I created with the upgrades, Mesos would fail with error

```
I0807 16:47:34.699182 21059 executor.cpp:190] Received LAUNCH event
I0807 16:47:34.699383 21059 executor.cpp:722] Starting task driver-20200807164731-0014
I0807 16:47:34.705006 21059 executor.cpp:738] Forked command at 21068
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/var/lib/mesos-slave/slaves/38e5abe1-7fa3-431c-a8f7-c3ed02458dcf-S0/frameworks/f9ba2f70-4709-466d-8e63-baae3c7eca42-0000/executors/driver-20200807164731-0014/runs/6b1ea2c9-5a46-4c49-8f47-fafaabe9395b/spark-3.0.0-executor/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.0.0.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Error: Failed to load class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi.
I0807 16:47:37.503019 21059 executor.cpp:1039] Command exited with status 101 (pid: 21068)
I0807 16:47:38.504026 21067 process.cpp:935] Stopped the socket accept loop
```

Here's what I tried:

1. Using the examples code from spark in case the problem is related to our code but got the same error.
2. We normally used spark rest api but I also tried spark-submit which produces the same error with deploy mode = cluster.
3. Both our product code and spark example code would run using spark-submit if deploy mode is client.
4. Temporarily removed noexec from /tmp but still got same error.
5. Temporarily stop iptables.

Our code would run if ran as standalone jar or using spark-submit when skipping --deploy-mode cluster option.

UPDATE #1:

1. Rest API call (what we normally use):

```
curl --request POST \
--url http://server1.someenv.tech:7088/v1/submissions/create \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{
"action" : "CreateSubmissionRequest",
"appArgs" : [ "verbose", "deploy-mode=cluster", "dataframe-active=false" ],
"appResource" : "<some artifactory url>/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0.jar",
"clientSparkVersion" : "3.0.0",
"environmentVariables" : {
"MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY" : "/usr/lib4/libmesos.so",
"MESOS_SANDBOX" : "/tmp_spark",
"SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI" : "<some artifactory url>/spark-3.0.0-executor.tar.gz"
},
"mainClass" : "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi",
"sparkProperties" : {
"spark.executor.extraJavaOptions" : "-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp_spark",
"spark.driver.extraJavaOptions" : "-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp_spark",
"spark.jars" : "<some artifactory url>/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.0.jar",
"spark.driver.supervise" : "false",
"spark.app.name" : "StreamingConsumer",
"spark.eventLog.enabled": "false",
"spark.submit.deployMode" : "cluster",
"spark.master" : "mesos://server1.someenv.tech:7088",
"spark.executor.memory" : "10G",
"spark.driver.memory" : "10G",
"spark.executor.cores" : 2,
"spark.local.dir":"/tmp_spark",
"spark.cores.max" : 10,
"spark.ui.enabled" : "true"
}
}'
```

For spark-submit (only when debugging)

```
./bin/spark-submit --name <ConsumerName> --deploy-mode cluster --master mesos://<server>:<port> 
     --driver-cores 1.0 --driver-memory 10240M 
     --class com.concur.analytics.consumer.stream.Application 
     --executor-memory 10G --total-executor-cores 10 
     --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-D<envvar>=<somevalue> 
     --conf spark.master.rest.enabled=true --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=false 
     --conf spark.driver.supervise=false --conf spark.ui.enabled=true --conf spark.app.name=AppConsumer 
     --conf spark.cores.max=10 --conf spark.driver.memory=10G 
     --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-D<envvar>=<somevalue> 
     --conf spark.executor.memory=10G --conf spark.executor.cores=2 
     <myproduct jar artifactory url> <product arguments>
```

Comment: it is failing with 101 error, which means jar mapping issue in the executor. btw how your are running mesos & spark , in docker or local LFS. could you share me the command you are trying to run?

Comment: We don't use docker and install everything from our artifactory.  Btw, I noticed the spark folder uid and gid are different from what the previous verison had.  I have updated my post to include the mesos rest api call and the spark-submit call and the uid and gid of the spark folder.